# How to convert List<xxxx> into Map<primarykey of xxxx, xxxx> without iterate list in java?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

```
List<Student> list = fromStudentTable();
Map<Integer,Student> map = new HashMap<Integer,Student>();
for (Student i : list) {
    map.put(i.getDbid(),i);
}
```

Now I want to covert list to map without iterate list or any method in any plugin like google guava...

Comment: You can use java 8 lamda function.

Comment: Please try to demonstrate your attempts.

Comment: Well, someone will have to do the iteration. You can only hide it behind some library function.

Comment: @Thilo I think he wants internal iteration, so he needs a snippet with Stream, like current top answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 8 Streams :

```
Map<Integer,Student> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getDbid,
                                  s -> s));
```

This converts the List to a Map where each element of the original List becomes an entry of the Map (where `getDbid()` is the key and the `Student` the value).

Comment: Is this construct not just hiding the iteration, and iterate internally ?

Comment: @Xvolks Of course the list must be iterated in order for this Stream to be processed. Any code that converts a List to a Map would have to iterate over the List.

Comment: I'm unsure about the benefit of this construct vs. OP's one.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something likewise,

```
List<Student> list;
Map<TypeofPrimaryKey, Student> map = list.toMap(c-> c.getPrimaryKey(),c->c);
```

Comment: Pardon me, it's about ArrayList/LinkedList or etc want to display, actually it's 'XList' i put X at end mistakenly